# Magento cart SSL issue submitting data to an insecure locations

Tags: magento, ssl

i am using magento EE. in this when user submit couponcode then system redirect to non-secure.

full story:

1. i am using amazon payments so we need SSL on cart page.
2. i am posting couponPost on SSL but some how system redirect to non-SSL

when i submit any couponcode:

1. system post coupon code to SSL
2. automatically system redirect to NON-SSL
3. again system redirect to SSL

so on the way global notifications lost. any one has any idea what's going on.

same issue: http://www.tagwith.com/question_342501_magento-cart-ssl-issue-submitting-data-to-an-insecure-location

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an issue on this a while back when I was working with a merchant having a similar issue. The GitHub issue can be found [here](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-payments-magento-plugin/issues/184) along with a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

Check this controller file : **CartController.php**

Location: `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/`

Replace this line under `_goBack()` function :

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

to

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart',array('_secure'=>true));
```

Hope this helps. I suggest you to don't modify the core file. Simply override it [check this method](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/).